# Kernel build error: missing /lib/modules

Tags: kernel

Good day!
I'm a linux newbie and I have been trying to install a different kernel version to the one that came with my ubuntu distribution (16.04.4 LTS).
Configuring and building the kernel (4.15.7) both go smoothly but when I try to install it (sudo make install) I always get the following warnings and I wind up not being able to boot into the new kernel. I have searched the internet and tried the suggested solutions but still could not solve it.
This is what I get when I run sudo make install

```
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.15.7 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
System.map "/boot"
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.15.7 /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.7
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.15.7 /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.7
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.7
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.15.7
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.15.7: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_VgOuon/lib/modules/4.15.7/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_VgOuon/lib/modules/4.15.7/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.15.7 /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.7
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.15.7 /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.7
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.15.7 /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.7
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.15.7 /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.7
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.7
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.7
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.7.old
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.7
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.75
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.75.old
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

This is the output of uname -r
4.4.0-31-generic

Comment: Looks as if you skipped the modules. What commands did you use to build the kernel and modules what command to install the kernel and modules and how did you make an initrd and configure grub?